# Create an user in mysql with readonly access

Tags: mysql

```sql
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';

GRANT SELECT ON `databasename`.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Comment: What is the issue? and what is the question?

Answer (score 12):

Create new user

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

GRANT `type_of_permission` ON `database_name`

```
GRANT SELECT ON database_name.table_name TO 'username'@'localhost';
```

Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Here is a short list of other common possible permissions that can be used.

`ALL PRIVILEGES`- as we saw previously, this would allow a `MySQL` user full access to a designated database (or if no database is selected, global access across the system)

`CREATE`- allows them to create new tables or databases

`DROP`- allows them to them to delete tables or databases

`DELETE`- allows them to delete rows from tables

`INSERT`- allows them to insert rows into tables

`SELECT`- allows them to use the `SELECT` command to read through databases

`UPDATE`- allow them to update table rows

Answer (score 2):

create read only user

CREATE USER 'user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON database_name.* TO 'user_name'@'%';

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
> GRANT SELECT, SHOW VIEW ON databasename.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: FWIW this didn't work for me on 8.0.28. I had to expressly create the user first using the `CREATE USER` command, and then grant privileges to it, like @Mohammed Noor Alam did in his answer.